# NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' when presenting view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have developed an app that in testing has worked fine but when it has could live I have had some issues with crashes when presenting Modal View Controllers. The issue is in here some where:

```
NSLog(@"Looks like we made it here 1");

UIViewController *mtaViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mtaViewController"];
NSLog(@"Looks like we made it here 2");

[mtaViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
NSLog(@"Looks like we made it here 3");

[self presentModalViewController:mtaViewController animated:YES]; 
NSLog(@"Looks like we made it here 4");
```

and my output to the console is:

```
2012-06-14 09:26:24.161 appname[2013:707] Looks like we made it here 1
2012-06-14 09:26:24.165 appname[2013:707] Looks like we made it here 2
2012-06-14 09:26:24.166 appname[2013:707] Looks like we made it here 3
2012-06-14 09:26:28.866 appname[2013:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x343ac8bf 0x345fc1e5 0x342f5b6b 0x6d3fd 0x6e719 0x3778e7ff 0x37798d53 0x37798cc1 0x37838339 0x3783714f 0x37891d97 0x7ce1d 0x7cd47 0x3788eaa5 0x3776a81b 0x3776ffb9 0x34ec1ba7 0x36fe0e8d 0x3437f2dd 0x343024dd 0x343023a5 0x30b86fcd 0x37783743 0x84327 0x6b468)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I have set up in a function that I call when wanting to change view controllers and as you can see it makes it all the way down to "Looks like we made it here 3" so I suspect that there is an issue with line

```
[self presentModalViewController:mtaViewController animated:YES];
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check any array in mtaViewController, I dont see any array in your code so I'm thinking the issue is within mtaViewController. :)

Comment: This is definitely possible. But it could also be the case that this array is part of Apple's private implementation only their engineers know about.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning objective c and this is my initial thought and I dont work with storyboard. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you view controller **really** gets initialized? Just an idea but this line

```
[mtaViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
```

would do nothing if mtaViewController would be nil. In Cocoa you can send messages to nil without problems. Your app only will crash later when you try to do something specific with them. Does

```
NSLog(@"%@", mtaViewController);
```

tell you something useful? Please make also sure you connected everything in IB that has to be connected (if you aren't working everything out in raw code).

By the way. This is deprecated. Use

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help I have changed that, but it was not the bug. I have actually found out where it is breaking now and it doesn't make sense it should have crashed in testing but it didn't.

Comment: And what exactly was the bug? Everything else of the code above seems to be alright.

Comment: Basically when to the presentModalViewController is run it loads the viewDidLoad on mtaViewController which has an array in it that was messing up. But it should have done the same thing in testing so I am a bit confused by it.